# Не могу связать php-fpm и nginx

Tags: php, linux, nginx

Собрал `nginx` и `php`, но не могу привязать `nginx` на unix сокет `php-fpm`. Конфиг `php-fpm`:

```
[global]
pid=/var/run/php-fpm.pid
error_log=/home/cc_user/php-fpm.log

[www]
prefix=/home/cc_user
user=cc_web
group=cc_web
listen=/tmp/php-www.sock
listen.owner = cc_web
listen.group = cc_web
listen.mode = 0666
pm=ondemand
pm.max_children=5
```

Конфиг `nginx`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name postfixadmin.domain.com;
        root /home/cc_user/web/postfixadmin;
        include admin_only.conf;

        location ~* \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            # if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {return 404;}

            fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-www.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
```

При заходе на страницу, выдает ошибку `502 Bad Gateway`. Лог `nginx`:

```
2022/05/19 15:39:33 [crit] 573050#573050: *26 connect() to unix:/tmp/php-www.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: (мой ip), server: postfixadmin.domain.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-www.sock:", host: "postfixadmin.domain.com"
```

Сам сокет существует:

```
root@domain:~# ls -l /tmp/php-www.sock
srw-rw-rw- 1 cc_web cc_web 0 May 19 13:31 /tmp/php-www.sock
```

Я пробовал вместо `unix:/tmp/php-www.sock` писать `unix://tmp/php-www.sock` и `unix:///tmp/php-www.sock`: не помогло. Моей душе намного приятнее использовать unix сокет вместо порта, поэтому прошу такой вариант не предлагать).

Comment: Вообще, определенные плюсы в использовании сокетов есть, например, использование юниксовых прав на них... кстати, с правами на сокет у пользователя и группы, от имени котрых запускается php-fpm - всё в порядке?

Comment: @S.H. Как видите, у сокета права `rw` для всех, так же `nginx` работает от имени `cc_web`